# Resources не подключается

Tags: wpf, silverlight

В проекте использую файл ресурсов.

```html
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SH2.Model.Repairs"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SH2.Converters">
    <!-- Конвертеры -->
    <converter:TypeToVisibleConverter x:Key="TypeVisibleConverter" />
    <converter:TreeHierarchyConverter x:Key="HierarchyConverter" />
    <converter:ValueToStylePaneConverter x:Key="ValToStyleConverter"/>
```

Возникает ошибка "Имя TypeToVisibleConverter не существует в пространстве имен ...", и так со всеми подключениями.
Код рабочий, т.к в другом проекте точь-в-точь такой же код и все работает.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/SH2;component/Resources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Здесь выдается ошибка, что произошла ошибка при поиске словаря ресурсов, заменяя на другой проект (SH1) все находит, только нет ссылок на сборку другого проекта.
Подскажите, что я тут мог забыть указать?

Comment: А других ошибок в проекте нет? Это может быть наведённая ошибка. Убедитесь, что остальная часть проекта компилируется без проблем.

Comment: Да, одна ошибка была в другом файле, исправил, заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в остальной части проекта нет ошибок.

Дело в том, что XAML компилируется в код на C# (частично) на втором проходе компиляции. Если первый проход (нормальная компиляция C#-файлов) был не успешен, по код не генерируется, и старый код производит ложную ошибку.

Таким образом, ваша ошибка скорее всего наведённая. Если это так, приведите остальной код к компилируемому виду, ошибка должна исчезнуть.